# Java Jsoup: Retrieve only the article

Tags: java, jsoup, extract

Trying to retrieve the text of the article. I want to select all of the text within

```
<p>... </p>
```

I was able to do that.

But I only want to retrieve the text from the article body, not the entire page

```
Document article = Jsoup.connect("html doc").get();
Elements paragraphs = article.select("p");
```

The code above gets the entire text from the page. I just want the text between

```
<article itemprop= "articleBody">...</article>
```

I'm sorry if this was hard to understand, I tried to formulate the
questions as best I could.

Comment: as I understand you want a tag <article> that's somewhere inside a paragraph <p>? for that, you'll need to use another selector, something like paragraphs.select("article").text()

Answer (score 1):

`Elements#text()` will return text-only content of all the combined paragraphs (see here for more details https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)

Comment: I used that method when outputting.
for(Element p : paragraphs)
 writer.println(p.text());

Comment: @BorysZibrov no, I managed to solve it though by using Elements paragraphs = article.select("#article-body article");
Thank you anyways.

Comment: perfect! yes, I didn't read your question carefully enough, sorry about that. glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting on the `itemprop` attribute

```
        for (Element paragraph : doc.select("article[itemprop=articleBody]"))
            System.out.println(paragraph.text());
```

See [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more tips